# Conservation of angular momentum (mass on a string)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, conservation-laws, string

I have a mass $m$ attached to a string of length $l$. The other end of the string is fixed and the mass is rotating around the fixed point with an angular velocity $\omega$.

The mass is rotating due to the tension force of the string $T$, that points to the center of the circular motion.

If I cut the string there is no longer a tension force and the mass should carry on a straight path now.

However, the angular momentum of the mass before the string was cut was $L=I\omega > 0$ and the angular momentum of the mass after the string was cut is now 0 since $\omega=0$.

We were assuming a weightless string so the missing angular momentum is not in string as well.

What happened to the conservation of angular momentum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [angular momentum, $L$,](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/amom.html) about an axis is the product of the linear momentum $mv$ and the perpendicular distance between the direction of the velocity and the axis $r$, so $L=mvr$.
When the point mass was rotating in a circular motion about the axis at a distance from it $r$ with a velocity $v$ its angular moment was again, $mvr= mr^2 \cdot \frac vr= I \omega$ as $v=r\omega$.
Thus angular momentum has been conserved.

Answer (score 2):

The angular momentum is the same before and after. It is incorrect that $\omega=0$. From the perspective of the original axis of rotation the angular position is still changing with time. The difference is that now the radius is also changing.

Quantitatively, suppose that the point mass, $m$, is whirling in the $(x,y)$ plane in a counterclockwise (positive $\dot \theta$) direction at a constant distance $r$ from the origin and a constant speed $v=|\vec v|$. Suppose further that the string is cut precisely when $\theta=0$, so the position at that instant is $\vec r_0 = (r,0,0)$ and the velocity is $\vec v_0 = (0,v,0)$.

From that moment on there is no force (and no torque) on $m$ so by Newton's first law $\vec r(t)= (r,v t,0)$ and $\vec v(t)=(0,v,0)$. We can easily calculate $$\theta(t)=\tan^{-1}\left( \frac{v t}{r}\right)$$$$\omega=\dot \theta=\frac{r v}{r^2+t^2 v^2}$$ Note that this function starts at $\omega(0)=v/r$ and goes smoothly to $\omega(\infty)=0$, as expected. At the same time $I=m\vec r^2=m(r^2+v^2 t^2)$ so $L=I\omega=mrv$ is a constant.

Recall also that angular momentum is given by $$\vec L = \vec r \times \vec p=(r,vt,0)\times(0,mv,0) = (0,0,mrv)$$ which remains constant too.